# PostgreSQL sum quantity of children items

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a subscription service that delivers many items.
Subscribers add items to a delivery by creating a row in `delivery_items`.
Until recently subscribers could only add 1 of each item to a delivery. But now I have added a quantity column to my `delivery_items` table.

Given [this schema, and an outdated query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6c224/2) (on SQL Fiddle), how can I select the total amount of an item I will need for each day's deliveries?

This provided a table of days, and items being delivered that day but doesn't account for quantity:

```
SELECT
  d.date, 
  sum((di.item_id = 1)::int) as "Bread",
  sum((di.item_id = 2)::int) as "Eggs",
  sum((di.item_id = 3)::int) as "Coffee"
FROM deliveries d
JOIN users u ON u.id = d.user_id
JOIN delivery_items di ON di.delivery_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.date
ORDER BY d.date
```

Ideally, my query would be agnostic to the specifics of the items, like the id/name.

Thanks

Edit to add schema:

```
deliveries (TABLE)
 id int4(10)
 date timestamp(29)
 user_id int4(10)
delivery_items (TABLE)
 delivery_id int4(10)
 item_id int4(10)
 quantity int4(10)
items (TABLE)
 id int4(10)
 name varchar(10)
users (TABLE)
 id int4(10)
 name varchar(10)
```

Comment: something like `sum(if(item_id=1, item_quantity, 0)) ...`? sum up the quantity field or 0, based on the item type matching.

Comment: or perhaps use a sub select to aggregrate the quantity per item before the join.  so instead of join delivery_items di use `join (Select sum(item_Quanity), Delivery_ID, Item_ID from delivery_items group by Delivery_Id, item_ID) DI`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to JOIN your `users` table, because you're neither getting any data from it nor using it as your joining condition.

Here's your edited <kbd>**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6c224/3)**</kbd>

Using conditional `sum()` function would retrieve values of needed goods to deliver for a particular date.

```
SELECT
  d.date, 
  sum(CASE WHEN di.item_id = 1 THEN di.quantity ELSE 0 END) as "Bread",
  sum(CASE WHEN di.item_id = 2 THEN di.quantity ELSE 0 END) as "Eggs",
  sum(CASE WHEN di.item_id = 3 THEN di.quantity ELSE 0 END) as "Coffee"
FROM deliveries d
JOIN delivery_items di ON di.delivery_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.date
ORDER BY d.date
```

You could also look into [`crosstab(text, text)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) function. Result would be the same, but you can also specify query that produces the set of categories.

Though, if you want to get dynamic results when your `items` table has additional rows, you would need to wrap this up in a function and build the output columns and types definition, because:

> The crosstab function is declared to return setof record, so the actual names and types of the output columns must be defined in the FROM clause of the calling SELECT statemen

Comment: You're right about the `users` table. It was residual from the query I was working on before. Thanks for demonstrating the conditional inside sum. Should be helpful

Comment: I've included another way to achieve this result. You could also make a function to get categories (items) dynamically. If you are interested in how to do that I could also help you achieve this result later, since right now I'm unable to test the solution.

Comment: Do you mind accepting my answer, or is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: Accepted. I only hesitated in hopes of finding a method that would allow me to avoid specific id references and scale with new products. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've mentioned a solution for this in my answer.